# Hadoop namenode failed to leave the safe mode because of Exception while invoking setSafeMode

Tags: hadoop

I am running a hadoop cluster(version:cdh4.1.1). I have two HA namenodes set up.

**Step 1.**

when I try to start my namenodes I got this exception:

```
2013-03-27 16:52:21,282 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: Cannot start an HA namenode with name dirs that need recovery. Dir: Storage Directory /data/dfs/nn state: NOT_FORMATTED
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1192)
2013-03-27 16:52:21,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

**Step 2.**

Then I tried to  run : `sudo hdfs namenode -recover`, I got:

```
13/03/27 16:53:37 INFO hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode is ON. 
Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.
```

**Step 3.**

Follow the instructions, I did `sudo hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`, I got:

```
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
13/03/27 16:55:17 WARN retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking setSafeMode of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB after 1 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 996ms.
13/03/27 16:55:18 WARN retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking setSafeMode of class ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB after 2 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 2085ms.
......retrying......
Not retrying because failovers (15) exceeded maximum allowed (15)
java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode-01.local/10.**.**.24 to namenode-02.local:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's some weird kind of wizardry going on, you forgot to format the namenode (as the exception already says). If you haven't already done so, run `hadoop -namenode format`. Note that if you **have** formatted your namenode, this is destructive.

Comment: Is there anyway to recover?

Comment: Yes, I did, after formatting it works. As you said, it's a destructive move. Is there anyway I can recover from this without formatting?

Comment: @Shengjie The exception you got suggests that it wasn't formatted in the first place, i.e., there was no data on it.

Comment: yes, looks like that's the case, so that shouldn't happen after formatting and there is some data already. Thanks!

Comment: I've run the `hadoop -namenode format` command and still see this same problem.